# numpy 3D array shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I created a numpy array of shape (4,3,2); I expected following code can print out a array shaped 4 X 3 or 3 X 4

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((4,3,2), np.int32)

print(x[:][:][0])
```

However, I got

```
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

Looks like a 2 X 3? I am really confused on numpy matrix now. Shouldn't I get

```
  [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]
```

in stead? How to do map a 3D image into a numpy 3D matrix?

For example, in MATLAB, the shape `(m, n, k)` means `(row, col, slice)` in a context of an (2D/3D) image.

Thanks a lot

Comment: In `numpy the display is `(panel, row, col)`.  The first dimension is the outermost one.  In MATLAB `x(:)` ravels the array, making a (24,1) size.   `x(:,:,1)` selects the first panel.  Why did you try `x[:][:][0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x[:]` slices all elements along the first dimension, so `x[:]` gives the same result as `x` and `x[:][:][0]` is thus equivalent to `x[0]`.

To select an element on the last dimension, you can do:

```
x[..., 0]
#array([[0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

or:

```
x[:,:,0]
#array([[0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all slices at the same time in a tuple, like so:

```
x[:, :, 0]
```

If you do `x[:][:][0]` you are actually indexing the first dimension three times. The first two create a view for the entire array and the third creates a view for the index 0 of the first dimension